# TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list' python

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I Keep getting this error, It's so simple and error is about (-x) in function but I don't know how I can fix it.
Please help me.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
x = list(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
print (x)
def f(x):
    f = np.exp(-x)
    return f

y =f(x)

print (y)
```

Comment: Why do you make a list from the array `arange` gives you? Lists dont support putting a minus in front of them.

Comment: `x` is a list. You can't subtract a list.

Comment: Use `list(range(10)` is you want a list.  `np.arange(10)` gives an array, and for math like this you don't want to convert it to a list.

Comment: Your hidden patch works because `np.multiply(-1,x)`, converts `x` to an array and then applies the multiply.. `-x` fails because `-` is not defined for lists.  No math is defined for lists.  `numpy` functions can usually work with lists because they first convert them to arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Broadcasting isn't supported for vanilla Python lists. You should use `list()` *after* the operation involving broadcasting, like so:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
print(x)
def f(x):
    f = np.exp(-x)
    return f

y = list(f(x))
print(y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please use different names

```
import numpy as np
x = list(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
print (x)
def func(param):
    retval = np.exp(-param)
    return retval

y = func(x)

print (y)
```

for start.

Then, you make a `list` from the `np.arange`, python lists don't support the unary operation `-` (minus) as you are using in the function (i.e. `f = np.exp(-x)`)

`numpy` arrays on the other hand do support it.
what you can do is not convert it to python list, or only convert it to a python list later in the process (after using the minus)

Comment: Your code would print `NameError: name 'f' is not defined`

Comment: Thank you very much